# Best and easiest way to remove tracking markers from green screen video

Tags: after-effects, greenscreen, tracking, chromakey, visual-effects

I have this video :

From which I want to remove all tracking markers (black and blue tracking markers). I tried to use After Effects through Mocha and Content-aware-fill using these youtube tutorials :

But it doesn't work properly.

Please can you recommend some good tutorials or techniques to flawlessly and easily remove all those tracking markers from my video ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this quite easily without content-aware fill or anything like it. I'd tackle this by doing the following:

- create a rough shape for each tracking-point (the color doesn't matter)
- track each point using the native after-effects tracker and apply the track to the corresponding shape.
- All the shapes should now stick to their tracked point. Precompose all the shapes.
- Under "track-mattes" you can now select your shape-precomp as "invered alpha-matte". This cuts out the opaque areas of the shapes, effectively removing the tracking-points.
- Key your footage.

I hope this helped you, have a nice day!

Comment: I see. The rectangles you created are masks, and will not work this way, unfortunately. You need to de-select every layer and create a shape with the pen-tool, and you'll see that a new shape-layer will be created automatically. For a detailed tutorial on how to use the 2d-point-tracker I recommend you check out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqWWhChc8RA

Comment: You need to deselect all the layers by clicking somewhere below, where no layer is. If you use the pen-tool then, a new shape layer will be created.